# SQLAchemy is never able to locate specified column in row

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2000, pypyodbc

I'm new to SQLAlchemy (but not ORM's in general) and running into an issue where I literally cannot do *anything* useful. All I'm able to do is hard code my query, which is what I want to do.

Here is exactly what I'm attempting to do (see Python comments to see what does/doesn't work -

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table
import pypyodbc

connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://U:P@SERVER/DB'

Base = declarative_base()


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Items'

    id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True, module=pypyodbc)
sm = sessionmaker(engine)
session = sm()

# WORKS
for row in engine.execute('select top 1 Id from Items'):
    print(row)

# DOES NOT WORK
print(session.query(Item).get(111))
```

The error I'm getting is `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'Items.Id'"`.

The generated SQL is correct -

```
SELECT [Items].[Id] AS [Items_Id]
FROM [Items]
WHERE [Items].[Id] = 111
```

I know I'm pointing to the right database, because if I change `__tablename` to something non-existent I get an invalid object name error.
Why can't SQLAlchemy find my columns?

Comment: Try `engine.execute` with the generated SQL and inspecting each row object, do you get the correct columns and column names?

Comment: @univerio: The dictionary key, which I'm assuming is supposed to be the column name, is `items_id`.

Comment: Lower case? What happens if you change `__tablename__` to `'items'` and `id` to `'id'`?